# find *.cpp, *.hpp, *.c and *h files using regex and 'find' command

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
find . -type f | grep -E '\.(cpp|hpp|c|h)$'
```

How can I do this using just find command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find . -type f -iname \*\.cpp -o -iname \*\.hpp -o -iname \*\.c -o -iname \*\.h`

- `.` - Finds in current directory
- `-type f` - Finds all entries that are files
- `-iname \*\.cpp` - finds case insensitive name of file that is some string (matched with `*` backslashed by `\` so shell will not expand it to local filenames) than `.` backslashed so it will not match any character, than extension
- `-o` stands for "OR" so multiple conditions can be "ORed"

Also, as Matteo_Ragni stated in his answer, you can use `-regex` option which may be in your case much simpler.

Using GNU `find` may use `-regex` with proper pattern

`find . -type f -regex '.*\.[hpp|cpp|c|h]'`

As suggested by @MatteoRagni it is possibly better to use regex like this:

`find -regex ".*\.\(hpp\|cpp\|c\|h\)$"`

It depends mostly of which regular expression pattern types your `find` is supporting and which one is default. For more information please refer proper documentation of parameters `-regex`, `-regextype` and corresponding regular expression types.

Comment: @DevilaN unfortunately the regex (also regex not rexex) solution is not working, there are too many case in which it can fail (furthermore your modification is compatible ONLY with GNU find, not with BSD find regex engine, and for GNU find there are better regex like `".*\(hpp\|cpp\|c\|h\)$"`). Please remove it.

Comment: @MatteoRagni: Changed it a bit so it may be a good start for further searches in a land of regular expressions. Thank you for your input in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, without `find` command but with `bash` options and pathname expansion:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
ls **/?(*.[ch]pp|*.[ch])
```

`shopt` is the `bash` builtin command to set (with `-s`) options.

`bash` option `globstar` enables the `**` pattern in order to browse into nested directories and  option `extglob` enables the `?(...)` pattern to match the different file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Grep to find all occurrences of `.c` `.h` `.cpp`

```sh
grep '\.[chp]' file
```